# How to remove another debugger so that Visual Studio can debug script

Tags: visual-studio, vbscript

So I messed up and installed a crappy scripting program to debug VBscript before I realized that it could be done with VS.

So now, despite uninstalling the other debugger (seems it did not uninstall correctly), I receive the following error message: "another debugger has registered itself as the Just-In-Time debugger" and will not allow me to enable script debugging in VS.

So looking into the issue it seems that the error is in the windows register somewhere but despite me trying a few things I have not found a way to fix this. I have tried to do the VS repair a few times after making Reg changes with no luck.

I feeling like this should be a easy thing but can't seems to find the answer anywhere, help if you can.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbGKZ.png)

Comment: Reinstall VS. That should restore all debugger registry entries. You may be able to go to control panel, and repair the install rather than remove it to fix the issue.

Comment: Does this help: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/configuring-automatic-debugging Could check the AeDebug key.

Comment: I have Reinstalled/Repaired a few times and haven't got this to work.

Comment: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug" does seem to have the right values. just to make sure I went ahead and deleted debugger value. This unchecked both managed and native jit check boxes, but script stayed unchanged. current value is "C:\windows\system32\vsjitdebugger.exe" -p %ld -e %ld

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this Chris? I'm getting the same problem while trying to debug XUnit tests.

Comment: Nope, I ending up just installing VS on another computer. Work like a charm there so there was in fact a problem with the Reg or something in windows.